# Mailchimp and Gmail: cant'd see padding

Tags: css, gmail, padding, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm working on a Newsletter using Mailchimp. I've got a lot of issues with Gmail.
To be specific: i know that Gmail does not supports CSS, so I'm writing the **style** into the **HTML**. Everything is okay but not the padding for the buttons and text: it's not displayed on Gmail.

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" class="columnsContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;max-width: 298px; align:left; text-align: left;">
```

[image]

How can i solve it?

Comment: if you are using table then set the height and width for that. eg; `<td><div style="width:[n]px;margin:auto;height:[n]px">Button</div></td>`

Comment: @CodeRomeos hi, yes i'm using the table tag. I just EDITED the first post. Now you can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this.

```html
<table width="50%">
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid red"><div style="width:180px;text-align:center;margin:20px auto;border:1px solid red;height:30px;line-height:30px;">Button</div>fake padding</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="border:1px solid red"><div style="width:80%;text-align:justify;margin:20px auto;border:1px solid red;">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>fake padding</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Do let us know if any issue.!